# Add data dynamically to an grid Array

Tags: php, cakephp

I have one array, the problem is I want to add some field in array ,which is common to  every model for save action .So please suggest me appropriate solution to add field value on runtime into array using any loop. My Demo array is

```
Array
(
    [submit1] => Submit
    [Customer] => Array
        (
            [Code] => CUS-14-15-016
            [Name] => hggh
            [CreditLimit] => 
            [CreditDays] => 
            [Currency] => $
            [CreditTerm] => 
            [Category] => 
            [AmountDue] => 
            [SuspensionFrom] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 04
                    [day] => 01
                    [year] => 2014
                )

            [SuspensionTo] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 04
                    [day] => 01
                    [year] => 2014
                )

            [SuspensionReason] => 
        )

    [ContactAddress] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 0
                    [Deleted] => 0
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                    [Address] => gsdgs
                    [City] => gs
                    [State] => gfsd
                    [Country] => sdgsf
                    [ZipCode] => gsgd
                    [EmailId] => 
                    [Mobile] => 0
                    [Phone] => 0
                    [Fax] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 0
                    [Deleted] => 0
                    [IsDirty] => 1
                    [Address] => sfvg
                    [City] => gfdgf
                    [State] => fdg
                    [Country] => dhgdh
                    [ZipCode] => 
                    [EmailId] => 
                    [Mobile] => 0
                    [Phone] => 0
                    [Fax] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I want to add 
$create = array('CreatedBy' => '1', 'ModifiedBy'=>'', 'CreatedDate'=>date('Y-m-d'), 'ModifiedDate'=>date('Y-m-d'));
this field value to Customer and Contact Address array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about cakephp, but may be

```php
$demo_array['Customer']=array_merge($demo_array['Customer'],$create);
$demo_array['ContactAddress']=array_merge($demo_array['ContactAddress'], array('Modified'=>date('Y-m-d')));
```

Comment: I add data from customer form in that it contain header part data and grid data . so i want to add about $create array field both line and grid array at runtime because both save query contain save code..!

Answer (score 0):

Cake fills fields like `created` and `modified` automatically, so you could use that and rename your fields in your db, if that is possible. Only thing you have to take care of is that in your db those fields are type `DATETIME` I think.

And if you want to add some fields you can use [model callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html) and put that in your `AppModel` or you can create custom behavior if you only have couple of models using that dynamically created data array.

Comment: I add data from customer form in that it contain header part data and grid data . so i want to add about $create array field both line and grid array at runtime because both save query contain save code..!